# How to avoid calling get_query_set()

Tags: django, admin

How can I make Django avoid calling ChangeList's get_query_set() method in file django.contrib.admin.views.main.py? I don't want to append any data, I want it to not call that method at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could always subclass (or monkeypatch) the `ChangeList` class and replace `get_query_set()` with a dummy. I can't work out why you'd want to do that though - it would mean you wouldn't get any data in the changelist page.

Comment: Because I wanna filter the data myself (advanced search). Was hoping there was some solution without monkeypatching it. Thanks though.